# Why the BLE Cliente example works on Arduino IDE but dont work on the Vscode PlatformIO

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

Im a student trying to read the temperature on a generic BLE Beacon using a ESP32-WROOM-32U. When i use the BLE client example on the Arduino IDE Version 1.8.19 using the native lib "ESP32 BLE Arduino" it works well, read the temp, all ok.

But when i upload the exactly same code using VsCode 1.69.1 and the same lib "ESP32 BLE Arduino" Version 2.0.0, compile and upload, but when it run, i get this error:

```
  Forming a connection to d4:b4:96:29:d5:b0
     - Created client
     - Connected to server
    
    Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (Unhandled debug exception). 
    Debug exception reason: Stack canary watchpoint triggered (BTU_TASK)
    Core  0 register dump:
    PC      : 0x40094f33  PS      : 0x00060b36  A0      : 0x80096c48  A1      : 0x3ffd0310
    A2      : 0x3ffb6c34  A3      : 0xb33fffff  A4      : 0x0000abab  A5      : 0x00060b23
    A6      : 0x00060b23  A7      : 0x0000cdcd  A8      : 0x0000cdcd  A9      : 0xffffffff  
    A10     : 0x00000000  A11     : 0x00000000  A12     : 0x00000008  A13     : 0x00000008  
    A14     : 0x007b6c34  A15     : 0x003fffff  SAR     : 0x0000001a  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000001
    EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x4008fd48  LEND    : 0x4008fd5e  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000
    
    
    Backtrace:0x40094f30:0x3ffd03100x40096c45:0x3ffd0350 0x40096c6f:0x3ffd0370 0x40096ebc:0x3ffd0390 0x400834c6:0x3ffd03b0 0x400834d9:0x3ffd03e0 0x40083509:0x3ffd0400 0x40097305:0x3ffd0420 0x40097320:0x3ffd0440 0x401125c1:0x3ffd0460 0x40111d95:0x3ffd0480 0x40105149:0x3ffd04a0 0x401040b3:0x3ffd04c0 0x40128c41:0x3ffd04f0 0x40128d8f:0x3ffd0510 0x40128ed2:0x3ffd0530 0x400fbe25:0x3ffd0570 0x400fb295:0x3ffd0800 0x40115612:0x3ffd0820 0x40115750:0x3ffd0860 0x40115afa:0x3ffd0880 0x40115bb9:0x3ffd0b10 0x40115bd7:0x3ffd0b30 0x40115b9f:0x3ffd0b50 0x40115bd7:0x3ffd0b70 0x40115b9f:0x3ffd0b90 0x40115bd7:0x3ffd0bb0 0x40115b9f:0x3ffd0bd0 0x40115bd7:0x3ffd0bf0 0x40115b9f:0x3ffd0c10 0x40115bd7:0x3ffd0c30 0x40115b9f:0x3ffd0c50 0x40115bd7:0x3ffd0c70 0x40115b9f:0x3ffd0c90 0x40115cf6:0x3ffd0cb0 0x40100af1:0x3ffd0cd0 0x400fbe5e:0x3ffd0f70 0x400fc309:0x3ffd1200 0x400fccc1:0x3ffd1260 0x400fdffc:0x3ffd12a0 0x400fe032:0x3ffd12c0 0x40109299:0x3ffd12e0 0x400f9e18:0x3ffd1470 0x40112977:0x3ffd1490
    
    
    
    
    ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000

    Rebooting...
```

I understand that in someway my code is making a stackoverflow, i already tried to modify the partition scheme using this https://geekelectronick.com/esp32-customizing-partition-in-platformio/ and reducing the massive use of serial.print but dont work.

I tried some of the tips here https://github.com/nkolban/esp32-snippets/issues/874 but dont work too.

The configuration on platformio.ini:

```
[env:esp32dev]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32dev
framework = arduino
monitor_speed = 115200
```

Below the code im using:

```
 /**
     * A BLE client example that is rich in capabilities.
     * There is a lot new capabilities implemented.
     * author unknown
     * updated by chegewara
     */
    #include "arduino.h"
    #include "BLEDevice.h"
    
    
    // The remote service we wish to connect to.
    static BLEUUID serviceUUID("0000AA20");
    // The characteristic of the remote service we are interested in.
    static BLEUUID    charUUID("0000AA21");
       
    String addr = String("d4:b4:96:29:d5:b0");  
    
    static boolean doConnect = false;
    static boolean connected = false;
    static boolean doScan = false;
    static BLERemoteCharacteristic* pRemoteCharacteristic;
    static BLEAdvertisedDevice* myDevice;
    
    static void notifyCallback(
      BLERemoteCharacteristic* pBLERemoteCharacteristic,
      uint8_t* pData,
      size_t length,
      bool isNotify) {
        Serial.print("Notify callback for characteristic ");
        Serial.print(pBLERemoteCharacteristic->getUUID().toString().c_str());
        Serial.print(" of data length ");
        Serial.println(length);
        Serial.print("data: ");
        Serial.println((char*)pData);
    }
    
    class MyClientCallback : public BLEClientCallbacks {
      void onConnect(BLEClient* pclient) {
      }
    
      void onDisconnect(BLEClient* pclient) {
        connected = false;
        Serial.println("onDisconnect");
      }
    };
    
    bool connectToServer() {
        Serial.print("Forming a connection to ");
        Serial.println(myDevice->getAddress().toString().c_str());
        
        BLEClient*  pClient  = BLEDevice::createClient();
        Serial.println(" - Created client");
    
        pClient->setClientCallbacks(new MyClientCallback());
    
        // Connect to the remove BLE Server.
        pClient->connect(myDevice);  // if you pass BLEAdvertisedDevice instead of address, it will be recognized type of peer device address (public or private)
        Serial.println(" - Connected to server");
        
    
        // Obtain a reference to the service we are after in the remote BLE server.
        BLERemoteService* pRemoteService = pClient->getService(serviceUUID);
        if (pRemoteService == nullptr) {
          Serial.print("Failed to find our service UUID: ");
          Serial.println(serviceUUID.toString().c_str());
          pClient->disconnect();
          return false;
        }
        Serial.println(" - Found our service");
    
    
        // Obtain a reference to the characteristic in the service of the remote BLE server.
        pRemoteCharacteristic = pRemoteService->getCharacteristic(charUUID);
        if (pRemoteCharacteristic == nullptr) {
          Serial.print("Failed to find our characteristic UUID: ");
          Serial.println(charUUID.toString().c_str());
          pClient->disconnect();
          return false;
        }
        Serial.println(" - Found our characteristic");
    
        // Read the value of the characteristic.
        if(pRemoteCharacteristic->canRead()) {
          std::string value = pRemoteCharacteristic->readValue();
          Serial.print("The characteristic value was: ");
          Serial.println(value.c_str());
        }
    
        if(pRemoteCharacteristic->canNotify())
          pRemoteCharacteristic->registerForNotify(notifyCallback);
    
        connected = true;
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Scan for BLE servers and find the first one that advertises the service we are looking for.
     */
    class MyAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks: public BLEAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks {
     /**
       * Called for each advertising BLE server.
       */
      void onResult(BLEAdvertisedDevice advertisedDevice) {
        Serial.print("BLE Advertised Device found: ");
        Serial.println(advertisedDevice.toString().c_str());
      String result = advertisedDevice.getAddress().toString().c_str();
    
        // We have found a device, let us now see if it contains the service we are looking for.
        if (advertisedDevice.haveServiceUUID() && advertisedDevice.isAdvertisingService(serviceUUID) && result.compareTo(addr)==0) {
          BLEDevice::getScan()->stop();
          myDevice = new BLEAdvertisedDevice(advertisedDevice);
          doConnect = true;
          doScan = true;
    
        } // Found our server
      } // onResult
    }; // MyAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks
    
    
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(115200);
      Serial.println("Starting Arduino BLE Client application...");
      BLEDevice::init("");
    
      // Retrieve a Scanner and set the callback we want to use to be informed when we
      // have detected a new device.  Specify that we want active scanning and start the
      // scan to run for 5 seconds.
      BLEScan* pBLEScan = BLEDevice::getScan();
      pBLEScan->setAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks(new MyAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks());
      pBLEScan->setInterval(1349);
      pBLEScan->setWindow(449);
      pBLEScan->setActiveScan(true);
      pBLEScan->start(60, false);
    } // End of setup.
    
    
    // This is the Arduino main loop function.
    void loop() {
    
      // If the flag "doConnect" is true then we have scanned for and found the desired
      // BLE Server with which we wish to connect.  Now we connect to it.  Once we are 
      // connected we set the connected flag to be true.
      if (doConnect == true) {
        if (connectToServer()) {
          Serial.println("We are now connected to the BLE Server.");
        } else {
          Serial.println("We have failed to connect to the server; there is nothin more we will do.");
        }
        doConnect = false;
      }
    
      // If we are connected to a peer BLE Server, update the characteristic each time we are reached
      // with the current time since boot.
      if (connected) {
        String newValue = "Canopus: " + String(millis()/1000);
        pRemoteCharacteristic->writeValue(newValue.c_str(), newValue.length());
        Serial.print("\r\n - Result sensor");
        std::string value = pRemoteCharacteristic->readValue(); 
        Serial.printf("\r\nLength : %d\r\n", value.length()); 
        Serial.print(" 0x"); Serial.print((uint8_t)value[0], HEX); 
        Serial.print(" 0x"); Serial.print((uint8_t)value[1], HEX);
        Serial.print(" 0x"); Serial.print((uint8_t)value[2], HEX);
        Serial.print(" 0x"); Serial.print((uint8_t)value[3], HEX);
        Serial.print(" 0x"); Serial.print((uint8_t)value[4], HEX);
        Serial.print(" 0x"); Serial.print((uint8_t)value[5], HEX);
    
        float temp = value[1]*100+value[2];
        if(value[1]==1)
        {
          temp=temp*-1;
        }
        Serial.printf("\r\nTemp: %.02f*C", temp/100); 
        float humi = value[4]*100+value[5];
        Serial.printf("\r\nHumi: %.02f/%", humi/100); 
                      
      }else if(doScan){
        BLEDevice::getScan()->start(0);  // this is just example to start scan after disconnect, most likely there is better way to do it in arduino
      }
      
      delay(10); // Delay a second between loops.
    } // End of loop
```

Comment: I think it's failing at here: BLERemoteService* pRemoteService = pClient->getService(serviceUUID); because the print before succeeded and before the error message the consequent error print is not  executed (failed to find our service uuid) and it didn’t print “found our characteristic”. Because pointers are used and the canary is mentioned I expect the problem here. And check the stacksize of the btu task. Isn’t that in menuconfig?

Comment: NB: CONFIG_BT_BTU_TASK_STACK_SIZE

Comment: Hi, thanks for your insight. I dont understand how the code work when upload with arduino IDE but dont work when i use the Vscode. On the BTU Stack size, i already changed it on the SDKCONFIG on C:\Users\USER\.platformio\packages\framework-arduinoespressif32\tools\sdk\esp32 to CONFIG_BT_BTU_TASK_STACK_SIZE=8192, but i get the same error.

Comment: It’s a time ago I did Arduino/ESP, I remember at that time changing sdkconfig changes were ignored.

Comment: It can be my problem! And how you solve this and force the Vscode accept the changes?

Comment: Maybe there is a workaround now, but that’s when I decided to use esp-idf on vscode instead of arduino.

Comment: Solved RemyHx. Posted the answer.

Comment: Very good! Nice to hear.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration on platformio.ini:

platform = espressif32

Then instead of writing this, write

platform = espressif32@3.5.0
and reupload.

Otherwise with the more recent versions you get a 2.x core. (Releases · platformio/platform-espressif32 · GitHub)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).